# Is there a simple way to see what services are being waited for?

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While setting up new nodes, I find that I'm often trying to debug if I've set the remapping correctly, or what service a node is waiting for to finish starting up. Is there a simple way to list what services are being waited for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10748/is-there-a-simple-way-to-see-what-services-are-being-waited-for?/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is no way of knowing what services are being waited for.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use roswtf, it will tell you which topics are still not being connected.

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-28**:
But I don't think it has any way to find which services a node is waiting for...